# taking tick marks as a reference point

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using the following code, I draw the lines manually after trials and errors to locate the coordinates of the tick marks. Is there a way to take the tick marks positions as references to draw from.

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\begin{axis}[ axis lines=center,axis line style={black, thick,-latex},
axis y line=left,axis x line=bottom,
 tick style={line width=.04cm, color=black, line cap=round},
 font=\normalsize,color=black,
 xmin=0,xmax=64,
 xtick={0,16,32},xticklabels={0,16,32},
 ymin=0,ymax=16,
 ytick={4,8},yticklabels={4,8},
 tickwidth=.2cm,
 xlabel={P}, xlabel style={right},
 ylabel={M}, ylabel style={above},
 xticklabel style={inner xsep=0cm, xshift=0cm,yshift=-.1cm},
 yticklabel style={inner ysep=0cm,xshift=-.1cm,yshift=0cm},
 samples=200]
\end{axis}
\draw [ultra thick,blue] (0,2.84) -- +(-40:4.44cm) node [pos=.5,circle, draw, black, fill=black, scale=0.5]{} node [pos=0,circle, draw, black, fill=black, scale=0.5]{}  node [pos=1,circle, draw, black, fill=black, scale=0.5]{};
\draw [thick, black, densely dotted] (1.7128,1.424) node [black, xshift=.46cm, yshift=.05cm] {A} -- (0,1.424);
\draw [thick, black, densely dotted] (1.7128,1.424) -- (1.7128,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are other points which locations are related to the tick marks locations; as in the following drawing

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you draw *inside* the `axis` environment, you can use the `axis cs:` for that. To show that it works for arbitrary functions, I've added a 'complex' function. Note that I added the `clip=false` option to the axis to prevent the marks from being clipped.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\tikzset{
    declare function={
%        myslope2(\x) = 24 - \x*(24/48);
        myslope(\x) = 8 - \x*(8/32);
        mycomplexfunction(\x) = sin(60*pow(\x,1.2)) + 6;
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\begin{axis}[ axis lines=center,axis line style={black, thick,-latex},
axis y line=left,axis x line=bottom,
 tick style={line width=.04cm, color=black, line cap=round},
 font=\normalsize,color=black,
 xmin=0,xmax=64,
 xtick={0,16,32},xticklabels={0,16,32},
 ymin=0,ymax=16,
 ytick={4,8},yticklabels={4,8},
 tickwidth=.2cm,
 xlabel={P}, xlabel style={right},
 ylabel={M}, ylabel style={above},
 xticklabel style={inner xsep=0cm, xshift=0cm,yshift=-.1cm},
 yticklabel style={inner ysep=0cm,xshift=-.1cm,yshift=0cm},
 samples=200,
 clip=false]
    \draw[ultra thick,blue] plot[samples at={0,16,32},mark=*,mark options={black}] (axis cs:\x,{myslope(\x)});
    \draw[thick,black,densely dotted] (axis cs:0,{myslope(16)}) -- (axis cs:16,{myslope(16)}) node [black, xshift=.46cm, yshift=.05cm] {A} -- (axis cs:16,0);
    \draw[thin,red] plot[domain=0.1:32,smooth,samples=200] (axis cs:\x,{mycomplexfunction(\x)});
    \draw[thin,red,densely dotted] (axis cs:0,{mycomplexfunction(20)}) -- (axis cs:20,{mycomplexfunction(20)}) -- (axis cs:20,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

For the example image you showed, you need the function `myslope2(\x) = 24 - \x*(24/48);`. Just add the samples in the same way as above.

**Edit**
As pointed out in the comments by @TorbjørnT, using `\pgfplotset{compat=1.11}` or higher lets the `axis cs` be the default coordinate system inside the axis from `\draw` commands. Also if you use `\addplot` instead of `\draw plot`, the markers are not clipped when they protrude outside the axis area, so you don't need the `clip=false` option anymore. `\addplot` has some additional advantages, e.g. adding legend entries with `\addlegendentry{}` as shown in the following example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\tikzset{
    declare function={
%        myslope2(\x) = 24 - \x*(24/48);
        myslope(\x) = 8 - \x*(8/32);
        mycomplexfunction(\x) = sin(60*pow(\x,1.3)) + 6;
    },
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[fragile,t]
        \frametitle{1}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
            \begin{axis}[
                axis lines=center,
                axis line style={black, thick,-latex},
                axis y line=left,axis x line=bottom,
                tick style={line width=.04cm, color=black, line cap=round},
                font=\normalsize,
                color=black,
                xmin=0,
                xmax=64,
                xtick={0,16,32},
                xticklabels={0,16,32},
                ymin=0,
                ymax=16,
                ytick={4,8},
                yticklabels={4,8},
                tickwidth=.2cm,
                xlabel={P},
                xlabel style={right},
                ylabel={M},
                ylabel style={above},
                xticklabel style={inner xsep=0cm, xshift=0cm,yshift=-.1cm},
                yticklabel style={inner ysep=0cm,xshift=-.1cm,yshift=0cm},
                samples=200
            ]
                \addplot[ultra thick,blue,samples at={0,16,32},mark=*,mark options={black}] {myslope(x)};
                \addlegendentry{Simple slope};
                \draw[thick,black,densely dotted] (0,{myslope(16)}) -- (16,{myslope(16)}) node [black, xshift=.46cm, yshift=.05cm] {A} -- (16,0);

                \addplot[thin,red,samples=200,smooth,domain=0:32] {mycomplexfunction(x)};
                \addlegendentry{Complex function};
                \draw[thin,red,densely dotted] (0,{mycomplexfunction(20)}) -- (20,{mycomplexfunction(20)}) -- (20,0);
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that if you have `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` (or some higher version number), then `axis cs:` is default, and doesn't have to be given explicitly. And if you use `\addplot[ultra thick,blue,samples at={0,16,32},mark=*,mark options={black}] {myslope(x)};` instead of  `\draw plot`, then the marks won't be clipped, so you don't need `clip=false`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks I did not know that, I've adjusted the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You just need to say

```
\draw [thick, black, densely dotted] (A -| 0,0) -- (A) -- (A |- 0,0) ;
```

Complete MWE.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\begin{axis}[ axis lines=center,axis line style={black, thick,-latex},
axis y line=left,axis x line=bottom,
 tick style={line width=.04cm, color=black, line cap=round},
 font=\normalsize,color=black,
 xmin=0,xmax=64,
 xtick={0,16,32},xticklabels={0,16,32},
 ymin=0,ymax=16,
 ytick={4,8},yticklabels={4,8},
 tickwidth=.2cm,
 xlabel={P}, xlabel style={below},
 ylabel={M}, ylabel style={left},
 xticklabel style={inner xsep=0cm, xshift=0cm,yshift=-.1cm},
 yticklabel style={inner ysep=0cm,xshift=-.1cm,yshift=0cm},
 samples=200]
\end{axis}
\draw [ultra thick,blue] (0,2.84) -- +(-40:4.44cm) 
node [pos=.5,circle, draw, black, fill=black, scale=0.5,label=right:A] (A){} 
node [pos=0,circle, draw, black, fill=black, scale=0.5]{}  
node [pos=1,circle, draw, black, fill=black, scale=0.5]{};
\draw [thick, black, densely dotted] (A -| 0,0) -- (A)
-- (A |- 0,0) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I located the position of point A according to the tick marks locations. It just happened that it is in the middle of the line. So I need to start drawing from the tick marks location.

Comment: Please refer to the drawing I uploaded to my question. There are other points related to the tick marks, and I need to locate their positions according to the tick mark positions. So I need to start drawing from the tick marks location, not vice versa.