# taking tick marks as a reference point to draw outside curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Using the code in the answer in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440077/taking-tick-marks-as-a-reference-point), the attached top diagram is generated. Can the code be modified so that the red node B* could be drawn outside the plotted line, with the dotted line extending from x=27 to y=13; as shown in the attached bottom diagram. Also can the labels of the individual tick marks x=27  be shifted to the right, and y=13 be shifted up.

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{1}
\tikzset{
declare function={
    myslope(\x) = 24 - \x*(24/48);
    mycomplexfunction(\x) = sin(60*pow(\x,1.2)) + 6;
},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\begin{axis}[
 axis lines=center, axis line style={black, thick,-latex},
 axis y line=left,axis x line=bottom,
 tick style={line width=.04cm, color=black, line cap=round},
 font=\normalsize,color=black,
 xmin=0, xmax=64,
 xtick={0,12,24,27,48}, xticklabels={0,12,24,27,48},
 ymin=0, ymax=30,
 ytick={12,13,18,24}, yticklabels={12,13,18,24},
 tickwidth=.2cm,
 xlabel={P}, xlabel style={right},
 ylabel={M}, ylabel style={above},
 xticklabel style={inner xsep=0cm, xshift=0cm,yshift=-.1cm},
 yticklabel style={inner ysep=0cm,xshift=-.1cm,yshift=0cm},
 samples=200,
 clip=false]
\draw[ultra thick,blue] plot[samples at={0,12,24,27,48},mark=*,mark options={black}] (axis cs:\x,{myslope(\x)});
\draw[thick,black,densely dotted] (axis cs:0,{myslope(12)}) -- (axis cs:12,{myslope(12)}) node [black, xshift=.46cm, yshift=.05cm] {A} -- (axis cs:12,0);
\draw[thick,green,densely dotted] (axis cs:0,{myslope(24)}) -- (axis cs:24,{myslope(24)}) node [green, xshift=.46cm, yshift=.05cm] {B} -- (axis cs:24,0);
\draw[thick,red,densely dotted] (axis cs:0,{myslope(27)}) -- (axis cs:27,{myslope(27)}) node [red, xshift=.46cm, yshift=.05cm] {B*} -- (axis cs:27,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the green dotted line drawn to a different y-coordinate, use a different y-coordinate ... I.e. use `13` instead of `myslope(27)`.

That doesn't move the dot of course, so I used a second `\addplot` to create that one. (I changed `\draw ... plot` to `\addplot`, makes more sense to me inside an `axis` environment.)

For the ticklabels, you could make use of `extra` ticks.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{pgfplots} % loads tikz
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{1}
\tikzset{
declare function={
    myslope(\x) = 24 - \x*(24/48);
    mycomplexfunction(\x) = sin(60*pow(\x,1.2)) + 6;
},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\begin{axis}[
 axis lines=center,
 axis line style={black, thick,-latex},
 axis y line=left,axis x line=bottom,
 tick style={line width=.04cm, color=black, line cap=round},
 xmin=0, xmax=64,
 xtick={0,12,24,48}, 
 ymin=0, ymax=30,
 ytick={12,18,24}, 
 tickwidth=.2cm,
 xlabel={P}, xlabel style={above}, % changed right to above
 ylabel={M}, ylabel style={right}, % changed above to right
 xticklabel style={inner xsep=0cm, xshift=0cm,yshift=-.1cm},
 yticklabel style={inner ysep=0cm,xshift=-.1cm,yshift=0cm},
 % specify extra ticks and modifications to their style
 extra x ticks={27},
 extra y ticks={13},
 extra x tick style={xticklabel style={xshift=5pt}},
 extra y tick style={yticklabel style={yshift=5pt}}
]

\addplot [ultra thick, blue, samples at={0,12,24,48},mark=*,mark options={black}] {myslope(x)};
\addplot [ultra thick, mark=*] coordinates {(27,13)};

\draw[thick,black,densely dotted] (axis cs:0,{myslope(12)}) -| node [above right] {A}(axis cs:12,0);
\draw[thick,green,densely dotted] (axis cs:0,{myslope(24)}) -| node [below left] {B}  (axis cs:24,0);
\draw[thick,red,densely dotted] (axis cs:0,13) -| node [above right] {B*} (axis cs:27,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In the code above I removed the `xticklabels` and `yticklabels`, as they didn't seem necessary. On the other hand, when manually specifying them, you can use that to move some of them around a bit. For example `xticklabels={0,12,\llap{24},\rlap{27},48},...,yticklabels={\raisebox{-10pt}{12},\raisebox{5pt}{13},18,24}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{pgfplots} % loads tikz
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{1}
\tikzset{
declare function={
    myslope(\x) = 24 - \x*(24/48);
    mycomplexfunction(\x) = sin(60*pow(\x,1.2)) + 6;
},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\begin{axis}[
 axis lines=center,
 axis line style={black, thick,-latex},
 axis y line=left,axis x line=bottom,
 tick style={line width=.04cm, color=black, line cap=round},
 xmin=0, xmax=64,
 xtick={0,12,24,27,48}, xticklabels={0,12,\llap{24},\rlap{27},48},
 ymin=0, ymax=30,
 ytick={12,13,18,24},  yticklabels={\raisebox{-10pt}{12},\raisebox{5pt}{13},18,24}, 
 tickwidth=.2cm,
 xlabel={P}, xlabel style={above},
 ylabel={M}, ylabel style={right},
 xticklabel style={inner xsep=0cm, xshift=0cm,yshift=-.1cm},
 yticklabel style={inner ysep=0cm,xshift=-.1cm,yshift=0cm},
]

\addplot [ultra thick, blue, samples at={0,12,24,48},mark=*,mark options={black}] {myslope(x)};
\addplot [ultra thick, mark=*] coordinates {(27,13)};

\draw[thick,black,densely dotted] (axis cs:0,{myslope(12)}) -| node [above right] {A}(axis cs:12,0);
\draw[thick,green,densely dotted] (axis cs:0,{myslope(24)}) -| node [below left] {B}  (axis cs:24,0);
\draw[thick,red,densely dotted] (axis cs:0,13) -| node [above right] {B*} (axis cs:27,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## Take 3

As Zarko pointed out in a (now deleted) comment, if you have `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}`, or with a higher version number, then `axis cs:` is default for `\draw` and the like inside an `axis`, so it doesn't have to be specified explicitly. I also removed the `axis x line`/`axis y line` styles, instead using `axis lines=left` and setting the position of `xlabel`/`ylabel` manually. I suppose use whatever method you prefer. Another minor thing, I used `ticklabel shift` instead of the more cumbersome `x`(`y`)`ticklabel style` with `y`(`x`)`shift` in your original code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{pgfplots} % loads tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11} % among other things, makes axis cs: default
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{1}
\tikzset{
declare function={
    myslope(\x) = 24 - \x*(24/48);
}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\begin{axis}[
 axis lines=left, % instead of center, removed the othe axis x/y line options
 axis line style={black, thick,-latex},
 tick style={line width=.04cm, color=black, line cap=round},
 xmin=0, xmax=64,
 xtick={0,12,24,27,48},
 xticklabels={0,12,\llap{24},\rlap{27},48},
 ymin=0, ymax=30,
 ytick={12,13,18,24},
 yticklabels={\raisebox{-10pt}{12},\raisebox{5pt}{13},18,24}, 
 tickwidth=.2cm,
 xlabel={P},
 ylabel={M},
 every axis x label/.style={at={(1,0)},above}, % manually position xlabel
 every axis y label/.style={at={(0,1)},right}, % manually position ylabel
 ticklabel shift=2pt % move all ticklabels away from axis
]

\addplot [ultra thick, blue, samples at={0,12,24,48},mark=*,mark options={black}] {myslope(x)};
\addplot [ultra thick, mark=*] coordinates {(27,13)};

\draw[thick,black,densely dotted] (0,{myslope(12)}) -| node [above right] {A}  (12,0);
\draw[thick,green,densely dotted] (0,{myslope(24)}) -| node [below left]  {B}  (24,0);
\draw[thick,red,densely dotted]   (0,13)            -| node [above right] {B*} (27,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Zarko I do of course know the bit about `axis cs`.  Regarding `axis lines=center` it *does* actually influence the output, in that it changes the position of the `xlabel` and `ylabel`. (Which of course could be modified elsewhere, but I just left it unchanged instead.)

Answer (score 0):

I never used the beamer class, so I tried this in article mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
            \draw[thick, blue] (0,24) -- (48,0);
            \draw[very thick,->,>=latex] (0,0) -- (55,0);
            \draw[very thick,->,>=latex] (0,0) -- (0,30);
            \filldraw[thick,densely dotted] (0,18) -- (12,18) node[above right]{$A$} circle (0.35)-- (12,0);
            \filldraw[thick,densely dotted,red](0,13) -- (27,13)node[above right]{$B*$} circle (0.35) -- (27,0);
            \filldraw[thick,densely dotted](0,12) -- (24,12)node[above right]{$B$} circle (0.35) -- (24,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It seems to provide what you want if I understood correctly. You can add the ticks on the axis easily.

Comment: A fine manual drawing; but I needed to make the tick marks as reference points, which is answered by the following answer. Thank you anyway.