# applying text in box inside a node to draw plot line

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code is from the answer to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440053/inserting-long-text-in-a-node-with-a-fixed-width). How to apply it to a draw plot line code from the answer to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440077/taking-tick-marks-as-a-reference-point).

I mean I want to apply the code of (inserting text in a box inside a node applied to the green line), to the blue line drawn by (draw plot within the axis definition).

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{1}
\tikzset{
declare function={
%        myslope2(\x) = 24 - \x*(24/48);
    myslope(\x) = 8 - \x*(8/32);
    mycomplexfunction(\x) = sin(60*pow(\x,1.2)) + 6;
},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, black, scale=.8, fill, node contents={}},
aligned pin/.style args={[#1]#2:#3}%
  {pin={[pin distance=10mm, pin edge={black, very thick, shorten >=-12pt},
    label={[append after command={%
      node[text width=35mm, color=black, fill=yellow!35, xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm, outer sep=0pt, inner sep=5pt,%
        at=(\tikzlastnode.#2),
        anchor=#1,
        ]{#3}}]center:{}}
        ]#2:{}}%
  },
scale=.9, transform shape]
\begin{axis}[
 axis lines=center, axis line style={black, thick,-latex},
 axis y line=left,axis x line=bottom,
 tick style={line width=.04cm, color=black, line cap=round},
 font=\normalsize,color=black,
 xmin=0, xmax=64,
 xtick={0,16,32}, xticklabels={0,16,32},
 ymin=0, ymax=16,
 ytick={4,8}, yticklabels={4,8},
 tickwidth=.2cm,
 xlabel={P}, xlabel style={right},
 ylabel={M}, ylabel style={above},
 xticklabel style={inner xsep=0cm, xshift=0cm,yshift=-.1cm},
 yticklabel style={inner ysep=0cm,xshift=-.1cm,yshift=0cm},
 samples=200,
 clip=false]
\draw[ultra thick,blue] plot[samples at={0,16,32},mark=*,mark options={black}] (axis cs:\x,{myslope(\x)});
\draw[thick,black,densely dotted] (axis cs:0,{myslope(16)}) -- (axis cs:16,{myslope(16)}) node [black, xshift=.46cm, yshift=.05cm] {A} -- (axis cs:16,0);
\end{axis}
\draw [thick,green] (0,2.84) -- node [dot, aligned pin={[south west]45:very very very very long long long  long text}] + (-40:4.44cm) node [pos=0, circle, draw, black, fill=black, scale=0.5]{} node [pos=1, circle, draw, black, fill=black, scale=0.5]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry, but i don't understand, what you like to obtain. add sinus wave to this picture?  no one example has green line.

Comment: The \draw [thick,green] (0,2.84) defines the green line with a text pinned to a node in it. I want to apply this text pinned to the node code to the blue line code (\draw[ultra thick, blue] plot) within the {axis}

Comment: and why this line is not in your mwe? please, make your mwe more complete.

Comment: The lines codes are in my mwe.     I tried (    \draw[ultra thick, blue] plot[samples at={0,16,32},mark=*,mark options={black}] (axis cs:\x,{myslope(\x)}) node [dot, aligned pin={[south west]45:very very very very long long long  long text}];
)  but the text is pinned to the end of the line not to its center.

Comment: The green line is over the blue line, if you enlarge the view you can see them

Comment: in my answer, which part you use in your mwe, is described how to do this: adequately change node anchor, from `south west` to for example `south`. and green line can not be seen in your image.

Comment: As I told you, the green line is over the blue line, you can see it if you enlarge the view. Please refer to my previous comment about my trial to apply the code to the blue line; and my edit of  my question for the added diagram of this trial application.

Comment: I tried to insert the node outside the blue line using the following code         \node at (axis cs:16,{myslope(16)}) [dot, aligned pin={[south west]45:very very very very long long long  long text}];
and it works fine

Comment: I solved my problem (as shown in the edit of my question). Thank you Zarko

Comment: You can answer your own question if you already found the solution

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following code `\node at (axis cs:16,{myslope(16)}) [dot, aligned pin={[south west]45:very very very very long long long  long text}];`
 and it works fine.